# Using _.countBy with ranges

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have a list of FICO scores that I'd like to group depending on their value, with groups starting at 0-620, then 620-640, incrementing by 20 every time.

What it should return is a count of values in each group -- 0-620, 620-640, 640-660, 660-680, etc. up to 780-800.

I'm currently using [`_.countBy`](http://underscorejs.org/#countBy) but it returns a count for every unique number, rather than for every group.

```
var counts = _.countBy(ficos, function(x) { return x }); 
//Counts should be {620: 22, 625: 19, 655: 24, 670: 20, 690: 30, 720: 29, 734: 17, 760: 21, 790: 18}
```

Is there a way to take advantage of `_.countBy` or some other function? I'm trying to avoid a long `if` statement, if possible.

Comment: You should add the example data you're using so we can test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So return the appropriate groups then:

```
function (x) {
    if (x < 620) return '<620';
    if (x >= 800) return '>800';

    var lower = Math.floor(x / 20) * 20,
        higher = lower + 20;
    return lower + '-' + higher;
}
```

Comment: I'm confused -- the OP is asking how to count which are in certain groups, and you're saying... what? I don't get it.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes I provided the function that groups input numbers into certain groups as per requirement.

Comment: No, you provided a function that gives the group of a given number. The requirement was that you group them. Building a list out of the results from this then using `_.countBy` would fulfill the requirements, but this alone does not.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes: that's correct - I provided a function that classifies an input into a particular group. Do you have any problems with my answer? I just cannot get what is your aim. It's obvious that this is just a parameter for `_.countBy` as that is what was question about. "Building a list out of the results from this then using _.countBy" --- that's not correct, you don't need to build a list additionally: this function + `_.countBy` is the complete solution.

Comment: But this doesn't parse a list. This parses a single number on the list --  you should provide the wrapper code so it actually does what the OP wants. Unless, of course, you can do integer arithmetic on an array in Javascript. Also, when providing an answer, it should be complete -- do not leave out details, no matter how trivial they are to you. Your answer should work without needing extra code.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes: it **SHOULD NOT** parse a list. Are you sure you completely understand how `_.countBy` works? "Your answer should work without needing extra code" --- my answer supplements the question. Stackoverflow is not about writing code for other people.

Comment: Wait, I'm being an idiot. My bad. I was confusing it with a similar method from Java.